# How to move single-word data between ARMv7 NEON vectors

Tags: assembly, arm, neon, armv7

I am trying to develop an assembly code using ARMv7 NEON vectorization. At some point, I need to copy a 32-bit value (single-word) from one NEON vector to another one, something like `mov dm[0], dn[1]`. When I checked the manual I could not find any `mov` or `vmov` operation which can do this logic since they need to have ARM registers `r` either in source or destination. Any idea or alternatives?

Comment: @PaulR he meant moving 32 bit words not the whole register.

Comment: ARM NEON has a very flexible variable byte-shuffling facility in `vtbl/vtbx`.

Comment: @EOF `vtbl` comes with a VERY long latency, and it keeps a register occupied. Not a very wise solution IMO.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE true, but as I said, it's a *general* shuffle. If the question is "how to move...", then `vtbl/vtbx` is a valid answer. If the question is "how to optimize this specific shuffle" it would probably not be.

Comment: @EOF It's NOT about optimization, but the feasibility. You shouldn't simply suggest `vtbl` without telling about the side effects.

Answer (score 2):

If you want:

1) mov d0[0], d1[0]

```
vext d0, d0, d1, #4
vrev64.32 d0, d0
```

2) mov d0[0], d1[1]

```
vtrn.32 d1, d0
```

3) mov d0[1], d1[0]

```
vtrn.32 d0, d1
```

4) mov d0[1], d1[1]

```
vext d0, d1, d0, #4
vrev64.32 d0, d0
```

Note that `d1` gets corrupted in case of 2) and 3). In order to avoid this, you should copy `d1` to a temporary register `d2` and use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

In 32-bit mode (ARMv7 and earlier, not ARMv8), each Q register aliases 2 `d` registers / 4 `s` registers.  e.g. `q1` is `d2..3` and also `s4..7`.  You can copy those separately.

I'm not sure if there's a merging penalty for writing an `s` register and then reading the containing `q` register on any ARM uarches.

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dht0002a/ch01s03s02.html has a register map: only q0..q7 have `s`-register aliases.  q8..q15 only have `d` register components.  (i.e. there are only 32 `s` registers, 32 `d` registers, and 16 `q` registers, so `d16..31` don't have their sub-components separately addressable, and `q8..15` only have 64-bit dword elements exposed separately).

If there's no better way to do this, then keep the vectors you need to slice and dice in the low 8 `q` registers.

---

ARMv8 (AArch64) introduced instructions that can index into vector registers because `s3` is the low word of `q3`: the overlap / packing is changed.

[image: AArch32 vs 64 SIMD registers]